# jQuery(document).ready(function() {} not work for SVG file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to execute this code in my website :

```
........
<div class="mapplic-tooltip">test:</div>

<div id="sparalesto"></div>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(".mapplic-clickable").click(function() {

        jQuery(".mapplic-tooltip").appendTo("#sparalesto");
    });

});
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

this is example of a element clickable , is a path tag for svg , like this :

```
<path id="path20646" fill="#B3B3B3" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.5206" d="M326.297,616.314l1.926,0.397v0.791h0.387
            l0.77,1.582h-0.77l-0.387,1.187l1.156-0.396l-0.384,1.187l0.77,0.793l-1.155,0.79v0.792l-0.387,1.186l-0.385-0.396v1.187
            l-0.77-0.396l-0.771,1.187h-0.771v1.585h-1.155l-0.385,0.79v1.583h-0.771v1.581l-1.541,0.792l-1.542-0.792l-0.77,1.188
            l-1.542-2.769l-0.771-0.396v-0.396l-0.386-1.186h-0.386h-2.312l-2.697-1.98l-0.385,0.397l-0.77-1.188h-0.772l-0.77-0.791
            l0.77-0.79l-1.155,0.395l-0.385,1.187l-1.156-0.396l-0.386-0.791l1.542-1.978v-1.582l-1.927-1.187l-0.771,0.791h-0.386v-1.187
            h-1.925v-0.792l-0.387-0.79l0.387-0.396l1.925-0.396l1.927-2.375l1.542-1.977l5.394-17.012v-1.979l1.542-1.978l2.697,0.79v-0.79
            l-0.771-0.791l0.386,0.396l-1.542-1.979l-1.155,1.584l-0.387,1.186h-0.385l3.854-15.823l0.385-1.978l1.542-1.979v1.187
            l-0.385,0.396l3.467,3.956l0.385,2.771l0.771-0.396v-1.979l1.926,0.395v-0.395v1.188l2.312,0.792v2.768l0.772-0.395l1.927,1.978
            l1.54-0.396l0.772,0.396l0.77-1.583l0.771-0.79l1.156,0.396l0.771-0.79l1.542-0.793v-1.582l0.384-1.188h0.771l-0.385-0.396
            l0.385,0.396l1.156-0.79h0.771l1.156-1.188v-1.583l1.156-0.395l1.155-1.187l1.927,1.187l-0.385,0.791l0.385,1.187l1.156-0.792
            l0.385,0.396h1.927l0.385,1.583h0.77l0.772,0.395l-0.772,1.187l1.542,0.791l0.771,0.397l-0.771,0.79l1.155,0.396l-1.541,1.188
            l-0.384,0.791l0.77,0.791l-0.77,0.791l0.77,0.396l-0.386,0.396l0.386,0.792l1.927,0.395l-0.771,0.396l0.771,1.978h-0.385v1.979
            l-0.386,0.396l0.386,0.395l-1.157,0.793v0.79h-1.155l0.384,1.188l-2.697,1.187v0.79l-1.156,0.792v0.396h-0.385l-0.77,0.792
            l-0.771-0.397l1.156,3.958l-1.926,0.395l-0.771-0.79l-0.386,1.186l1.157,1.188l-1.157,1.582h-0.77l0.77,0.396v0.791l-1.925-0.396
            l0.384,0.791h-0.771l-0.386,0.793l-1.155,0.79l-1.156-1.583l-4.237,1.583l-1.542-0.79l-0.77,0.79l-0.387-0.79l-0.77,0.396
            l-0.385,1.978l-1.156-1.188l0.386-0.396l-0.772-0.79l-0.771,1.186l-1.156-0.396l-1.155,0.396v0.396l0.77,0.792h-0.385v1.187
            h-0.385l0.385,1.582l-1.156,0.395v1.188h-0.386L326.297,616.314L326.297,616.314z" class="mapplic-clickable" style="fill: rgb(221, 51, 51);"></path>
```

but doesn't work, in the Chrome console I don't see never error.

Then I tried to load this script in the Chrome console after loading the website, and it works, why doesn't it work if I insert this before closing `</body>`?

Comment: @ nikhil |  yes i used ready, sorry is a error in copy/paste on stackoverflow

Comment: OP where is the "mapplic-clickable" element? There's nothing like that in what you posted.

Comment: Have you added a link in your header to a version of jquery?

Comment: @Pointy | the mapplic-clickable" element is a tag <path for svg , i have updated the question

Comment: @Chris G | sure , repeat, it's work when load this script in chrome console